# How to display Unicode decimals?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

Here is my code, which works fine, but it displays only hexadecimals:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
      function myfun() {
        var a= document.getElementById('anils').value;
        document.getElementById('anils2').value = "\u0C39\u0C48";
      }
    </SCRIPT>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="anil" id="anils" />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="anil2" id="anils2" />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" id = "anils1" onclick="myfun()" />
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

\u0C39\u0C48 is in hexadecimal but the equivalent decimal \u3129\u3144 is not displaying in my browser.

Comment: Not gonna work. Just use the hexadecimal one. (did you realise that 3129 and 3144 are also valid hexadecimal?)

Comment: why?the reason needed here

Comment: There's no reason other than there being no support for it.

Comment: then how html entities generated in decimal format?

Comment: Is `"\u3129"` and HTML entity?

Comment: If you want to use HTML entities, why don't you just use them?

Comment: &#3129 is html entity that was converted unicode

Comment: html not detects html entities in text box thats why i choosen unicode

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31666/discussion-between-anilhoney-and-r-martinho-fernandes)

Comment: I don't understand. You already have a working solution.

Comment: by default html generates decimal entities for unicode that i entered i text box but  how to make that one as hexadecimal ?  problem is browser detects hexadecimal entities(unicode) but it generates decimal entities

Comment: Add **x** for hexadecimal entities. &#64; is decimal, &#x40; is hexadecimal.

Comment: From the comments, it is obvious that the real problem is very different from the question asked.

Answer (score 2):

`\u0C39` is **not** an HTML entity. HTML entities are used in HTML context and look like `&...;`. Valid HTML entities for the [U+0C39 character (హ)](http://codepoints.net/U+0C39) include `&#3129;` (decimal) and `&#xc39;` (hexadecimal).

`\u0C39` is a [JavaScript Unicode escape sequence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Unicode_escape_sequences) and has no relation to HTML. The format is exactly that, `\u` plus a four-digit hexadecimal number that represents the Unicode code-point. Period. Any other format you might try simply does not exist.

P.S. `\u3129` represents [U+3129 (ㄩ)](http://codepoints.net/U+3129).

Comment: &#3129;&#3144;&#3110;&#3120;&#3134;&#3116;&#3134;&#3110;&#3149; go to this [link](http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/unicode-html-entities-convertor.php)  and give above entities y got some unicode how to display that in text box(unicode)

Comment: i have text in text box(హైదరాబాద్) i entered telugu language characters that went to server &#3129;&#3144;&#3110;&#3120;&#3134;&#3116;&#3134;&#3110;&#3149; in this format now i want to save this database and i want to display this entities back to format that what i entered first(హైదరాబాద్) how to do that

Comment: Just retrieve the values from the database and output them back into the HTML document (i.e. using `echo` for PHP)

Comment: @AnilHoney - There's absolutely no need to use HTML entities that way if your site is using UTF-8. [Are you using UTF-8 correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: please  can u show me directely that by using html and javascript like entere హైదరాబాద్ text in one text box and show it another text box

Answer (score 1):

From comments - this is no longer anything to do with the question as stated. Suggest update the question to match your actual problem.

> i have text in text box(హైదరాబాద్) i entered telugu language characters that went to server `&#3129;&#3144;&#3110;&#3120;&#3134;&#3116;&#3134;&#3110;&#3149;`

It sounds like your page is served without a specified encoding. Consequently the browser guesses what encoding to use to display it, and that encoding is probably not UTF-8.

When the browser submits the form, it uses the encoding of the web page. If that encoding isn't UTF-8 and so can't include the Telugu characters, the browser panics and tries sending the characters encoded as HTML character references instead. This is not a recoverable encoding, because you can't tell whether the character references are supposed to represent Unicode characters, or the user just deliberately typed `&#...;`.

To fix, ensure you include a `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` HTTP header with the form's HTML page, or include the equivalent `<meta charset>` tag in the page HTML.